# UINavigationController with a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController` called EditPoint in a `UINavigationController` that are presented in a `UIPopoverController`.

Sometimes EditPoint is the root UITableview, sometimes another `UITableviewContoller` pushes EditPoint.

Is there a way that I can tell in EditPoint TableViewController to tell if another one pushed it into view or if its the root?

I push EditPoint:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tableView animated:TRUE];
```

then in EditPoint I tried:

```
DLog(@"self.navigationController.presentingViewController: %@", self.navigationController.presentingViewController);
DLog(@"self.navigationController.presentedViewController: %@", self.navigationController.presentedViewController);

DLog(@"self.presentingViewController: %@", self.presentingViewController);
DLog(@"self.presentedViewController: %@", self.presentedViewController);
```

and they all return NULL.

But if I try:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
```

or any of the other pop methods, it works.

Any idea why I can't figure out what the `presentingViewController` is?

The end result is I need to tell if there is a back button or if I need to put a button there that says Cancel. Is there a better way to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use [self.navigationController.viewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) to check if self is the root view controller at its nav controller stack, the properties you are using should be used when the controller is presented as modal.

Comment: Ok, this should work. Interestingly, if you are on the root view, `self.navigationController.viewControllers` is NULL. And thank you for pointing out the presented/presenting is for modal transitions.

Comment: Neither of view controllers at nag controller stack should have `nil` at `self.navigationController.viewControllers`, but if you have `vc1` as a root view controller and `vc2.view` as subview of `vc1.view`, `vc2` has no information about nag controller. `vc1.navigationController.viewControllers` should return an array with itself.